# Setting "EnvironmentFile" through systemctl

Tags: systemd, systemctl

I have a service that needs to load an `EnvironmentFile`. I was able to get this working by manually typing out the filename in the relevant service file. However, I am trying to do this through a more automated approach, for example, using something like `systemctl`, so I do not need to edit files using regex.

I tried the following:

```
sudo systemctl set-property supervisor EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/supervisor
```

but was receiving the following error:

```
Failed to set unit properties on supervisor.service: Cannot set property EnvironmentFiles, or unknown property.
```

Is there a way to do this through `systemctl`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `systemctl edit` feature to do this. If done interactively then that's all you need. If you do it in a script then you can do this:

`SYSTEMD_EDITOR=tee  systemctl edit --user [your_unit_name] < $(echo "EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/supervisor")`

or for --system units

`env SYSTEMD_EDITOR=tee  sudo -E systemctl edit --system [your_unit_name] < $(echo "EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/supervisor")`

This will add a modifier in the `<unit>.d/override.conf` file.  I would advise against even trying to use the `edit --full` feature as it creates static units that are sticky and will mess up your enable/disable operations, (at least on Ubuntu, your mileage may vary).